# rabbitmq : Check if each rabbit hostname resolves uniquely to the proper IP address during the prechecks phase

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq, virtual-machine, openstack

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack on a virtual machine running CentOS 8.3.2011 by following [this link](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html), but I got an error on the pre checks phase when running the command:

```sh
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one prechecks
```

The error message was:

```
TASK [rabbitmq : Check if each rabbit hostname resolves uniquely to the proper IP address] *****************************failed: [localhost] (item=[{'cmd': ['getent', 'ahostsv4', 'localhost'], 'stdout': '127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost\n127.0.0.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.0.1       RAW    \n127.0.0.1       STREAM \n127.0.0.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.0.1       RAW    \n192.168.56.103  STREAM \n192.168.56.103  DGRAM  \n192.168.56.103  RAW    ', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-05-28 07:48:12.453408', 'end': '2021-05-28 07:48:12.455955', 'delta': '0:00:00.002547', 'changed': False, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'getent ahostsv4 localhost', 'warn': True, '_uses_shell': False, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': 'localhost', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}, '127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": [{"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "cmd": ["getent", "ahostsv4", "localhost"], "delta": "0:00:00.002547", "end": "2021-05-28 07:48:12.455955", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "getent ahostsv4 localhost", "_uses_shell": false, "argv": null, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "stdin_add_newline": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "warn": true}}, "item": "localhost", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-05-28 07:48:12.453408", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost\n127.0.0.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.0.1       RAW    \n127.0.0.1       STREAM \n127.0.0.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.0.1       RAW    \n192.168.56.103  STREAM \n192.168.56.103  DGRAM  \n192.168.56.103  RAW    "}, "127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost"], "msg": "Hostname has to resolve uniquely to the IP address of api_interface"}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The globals.yml setting `api_interface` seems to be set to 127.0.0.1. This address resolves to more than one name, which makes it impossible for Kolla-Ansible to determine the hostname for RabbitMQ. Best solution is to use the host's non-loopback IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced this issue in my control node where prechecks ended up showing failure status against my compute node. I went to look at its /etc/hosts file which has two entries for a single hostname (ubuntu in my case).

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE GENERATED HOSTS
192.168.3.133 ubuntu
192.168.3.137 ubuntu
# END ANSIBLE GENERATED HOSTS
```

I edited the file manually to contain only one entry (primary interface IP against username ubuntu).

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE GENERATED HOSTS
192.168.3.133 ubuntu
# END ANSIBLE GENERATED HOSTS
```

It worked and prechecks phase was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is better to proper setup the hostname of the testing machine to avoid this error.  This is what i did.

sudo hostnamectl set-hostname openstack-aio

then check /etc/hosts it should have an entry for localhost and another entry for the new hostname.

Don't forget to logout/login so your shell sees the new hostname.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file. Comment out the above two lines and make an entry against your ip to localhost

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/hosts

#127.0.0.1 localhost

#::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.122.73  localhost

[root@localhost ~]#
```